# renderAs="pdf" - what's wrong?

Tags: visualforce, pdf

Lets'say I've got a page

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false">
<header>
    <style>
        .testTable {
            border-spacing: 50px 1px;
            border : 1px solid red;
        }
        .testTr  td {
            width: 50%;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: bottom;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
     </style>
</header>
<body>
    <table class="testTable">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="testTr">
                <td>1345677</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

But I've got  in my opinion strange result 
[image: Result]
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you have to use `<head>` instead of `<header>`

Comment: Another point to note - in my experience the PDF renderer does NOT apply style from CSS. You must instead add explicit style attributes on the various elements.

Comment: @PhilW Not true, you just have to do it right.

Comment: Hmmm. What is "do it right" in this context? Can you point me to the documentation that covers the limitations? For me the CSS rendered fine when outputting as HTML but didn't work when rendering to PDF.

Comment: @PhilW There's ... no documentation I'm aware of. A lot of what we've discovered came from exploring the documentation for Flying Saucer. For example, we know that CSS2 is only partially supported, and CSS3 isn't at all. So basically you have to write your pages like it's 1996 (or so). A perfectly well-formed HTML document will apply the CSS correctly. If you have a specific example you'd like fixed, you could ask a question, I'd be glad to point you in the right direction.

Comment: In my case - it was my mistake with <head>. Css works fine

Comment: Moreover - border-spacing: 50px 1px; - that does not work (i think due to SF pdf renderer css 2 limitations)

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks for the info. Useful to know. Now I am aware it is partial CSS2 I can probably work out what the gaps were and work around them without "style" attributes. Great learning! Cheers.

Comment: @rael_kid I suggest you add your comment as the official answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `<head>` instead of `<header>`.